# MethodError at runtime for compiled version of a Julia application that otherwise runs fine

Tags: runtime-error, julia, packagecompiler.jl

I have a Julia application that runs fine, but I want to make a compiled and more easily distributable version of it. As far as I understood, this is the job of [`PackageCompiler`](https://github.com/JuliaLang/PackageCompiler.jl).

I'm able to build the executable, and it runs fine when just asking it for its `--help`, but when I want it to do some real work (processing data), after some initial info output, it crashes with the following error messages:

```
fatal: error thrown and no exception handler available.
MethodError(f=typeof(Base.convert)(), args=(Int32, nothing), world=0x00000000000065d9)
rec_backtrace at /home/bli/src/julia/src/stackwalk.c:94
record_backtrace at /home/bli/src/julia/src/task.c:219 [inlined]
jl_throw at /home/bli/src/julia/src/task.c:429
jl_method_error_bare at /home/bli/src/julia/src/gf.c:1606
jl_method_error at /home/bli/src/julia/src/gf.c:1624
jl_apply_generic at /home/bli/src/julia/src/gf.c:2161
julia_main at /home/bli/src/qaf_demux/Julia/QafDemux/bin/qaf_demux_to_compile.jl:12
julia_main at /home/bli/src/qaf_demux/Julia/QafDemux/deps/builddir/qaf_demux.so (unknown line)
main at ./deps/builddir/qaf_demux (unknown line)
__libc_start_main at /build/glibc-LK5gWL/glibc-2.23/csu/../csu/libc-start.c:291
_start at ./deps/builddir/qaf_demux (unknown line)
```

What does this `MethodError` mean? What useful information can I get from the backtrace?

Here is the `deps/build.jl` script used to compile it:

```
import Pkg
Pkg.add("ArgParse")
Pkg.add("IterTools")
Pkg.add("FASTX")
Pkg.add("CodecZlib")
Pkg.add("REPL")
Pkg.add("PackageCompiler")
using PackageCompiler
build_executable(joinpath(@__DIR__, "../bin/qaf_demux_to_compile.jl"), "qaf_demux", snoopfile=joinpath(@__DIR__, "../bin/snoop.jl"))
```

`snoop.jl` calls the main function of my `QafDemux` package with some test command-line (which corresponds to the one used to test the compiled executable):

```
#!/usr/bin/env julia

push!(LOAD_PATH, abspath(joinpath(@__DIR__, "../src/")))
import QafDemux
const qd = QafDemux

test_args = "-i ../../test_data/TCR_ampli_R1_50k.fastq.gz -o test_run -b GCAGAGATAAGC GCAGAGATGCAC GCAGAGACTCAG GCAGAGAGGAAT GCAGAGACGAGG GCAGAGAAGGAG GCAGAGATGTTG GCAGAGACAACT GCAGAGAGGCTA GCAGAGAGAATG GCAGAGACCAAC GCAGAGAGAGAC -s 3 -m 2 -p 0.1"
qd.main(split(test_args))
```

`qaf_demux_to_compile.jl`, as per the `PackageCompiler` instructions, is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env julia

push!(LOAD_PATH, abspath(joinpath(@__DIR__, "../src/")))
import QafDemux
const qd = QafDemux

Base.@ccallable function julia_main(ARGS::Vector{String})::Cint
    qd.main()
end
```

The non-compiled version, that works fine, is almost identical:

```
#!/usr/bin/env julia

push!(LOAD_PATH, abspath(joinpath(@__DIR__, "../src/")))
import QafDemux
const qd = QafDemux

qd.main()
```

(Cross-posted at a slightly earlier stage of my investigation at https://discourse.julialang.org/t/understanding-runtime-errors-with-packagecompiler-built-executables/29120/2)

---

#### Edit: Working solution

Based on the suggestion made by @[Anshul Singvi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8599432/anshul-singhvi), I modified the main function of my `QafDemux` module so that it now returns an integer, and use is so that this is also the return value of the `julia_main` function in the code passed to `PackageCompiler.build_executable`.

`bin/qaf_demux_to_compile.jl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env julia

push!(LOAD_PATH, abspath(joinpath(@__DIR__, "../src/")))
import QafDemux
const qd = QafDemux

Base.@ccallable function julia_main(ARGS::Vector{String})::Cint
    return qd.main()
end
```

(I also had to change the main function so that it accepts an optional command-line, because the snoopfile was actually wrong otherwise).

Comment: You may also want to check out https://github.com/NHDaly/ApplicationBuilder.jl depending on your use case.

Comment: It could be that you need to return an integer?  Try `return 0` at the end of your `julia_main` function.

Comment: @logankilpatrick I tried to use `ApplicationBulider` too, and the resulting executable had the same problem. That said, I'm not sure to understand the differences between `PackageCompiler` and `ApplicationBuilder`, except the place where the built files are put. It seems to me that in both cases, there still is no single-file standalone executable: both provide shared objects that need be shipped along with the executable.

Comment: @AnshulSinghvi That was (one of) the problems. Thanks. The other was that I hadn't noticed that the compilation failed due to the way I tried to simulate a call with command-line arguments in the snoopfile. The error I reported must have actually been generated using a previously compiled version, without a snoopfile.

Comment: @bli, did you get it to work?

Comment: @AnshulSinghvi Yes, thanks. Don't hesitate to post your comment as an answer, maybe with a word about what made you suspect this was the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the stacktrace, you can see that Julia is trying to convert `nothing` into `Int32`, in the line:

```
MethodError(f=typeof(Base.convert)(), args=(Int32, nothing), world=0x00000000000065d9)
```

This is because your `julia_main` function doesn't explicitly return anything, and `qd.main` also seems not to return anything.  In the absence of an explicit return value, Julia defaults to returning nothing.

However, in your method's type contract, it's specified that `julia_main` **must** return a `Cint`, which on your system seems to be an `Int32`.  Therefore, Julia is trying to convert what `julia_main` (implicitly) returns to an `Int32` - which is impossible!

To fix this, you just need to make sure that you return an integer.  A nicer thing to do would be:

```
Base.@ccallable function julia_main(ARGS::Vector{String})::Cint
    try
        qd.main()
    catch e
        print(stderr, e) # print the error to standard error
        return 1 # in command line tools, a return value of 1 means error
    finally
        return 0 # similarly, a return value of 0 means that the program ran properly
    end
end
```